# Executing python and bash commands using DockerOperator

Tags: airflow

Syntax to pass multiple commands (consisting of bash and python ) to the command parameter in DockerOperator
For example if I have mix of command like -> python test.py , mkdir -p /test  to be executed inside the docker container

Comment: Detail your question. What do you seek exactly? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

We achieved to run multiple commands with DockerOperator and retrieving the logs by filling the command argument like "bash -c 'command1 && command2 && command3'".

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple commands to the `command` parameter separated by `&&`, like this:

```py
command='(command1) && (command2) && (command3)'
```

So the full code looks like:

```py
t_docker = DockerOperator(
  task_id='docker_command',
  image='bde2020/spark-master:latest',
  api_version='auto',
  auto_remove=True,
  command='(python a.py) && (echo "done") && (mkdir /mydirectory) && (echo "directory created"))',
  network_mode='bridge'
)
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug because of which it does not take list input, I just reported it here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4763?jql=project%20%3D%20AIRFLOW%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20~%20%22dockeroperator%20command%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC

Comment: This does not work for me. Is there another way to execute multiple commands

Comment: I tried: command='(echo "done") && (spark-submit --master local[*] /home/jovyan/pyspark_test01.py)'

But got error: ERROR - docker container failed: {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 127}

Comment: Do you get the same error with `command='(echo "done") && (echo "again")`?